# CSS Page break on print in javafx pane

Tags: html, css, javafx

I am creating some html pages that are displayed in an application (Not mine, so i can't change anything). I'm trying to set some specific css to handle the print like this:

```
@media print {
  h2 { 
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  h3, h4 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  pre, blockquote {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

I can't find anything working any idea? I believe that the html pages are displayed by javaFx, it doesn't support this kind of css property? Any hint to handle page break in a javaFx panel?